Sci-fi book about an alien discovered frozen in a capsule in deep space
In the 90s I read a sci-fi book.
The book is about a space crew which discovers a frozen capsule in deep space which contain alien life which escapes from the capsule and threats life on space ship and nearby planet. The alien life can change its shape.
Once the capsule is discovered, the space crew sends one member to investigate. While the human is in the capsule, the alien form detects the presence of a human and wakes up from deep sleep mode. Then the alien form invades the spaceship. I do not remember in detail, but the alien form multiplies by converting the human host into their own kind and manages to escape the spaceship to land on nearby planet (not Earth) where it continues its expansion.
The alien form poses rapid movements; thus humans have hard time to resist. Moreover, the alien form develops some kind of ugly flaps/soft wings in its body. That is basically all details that I can recollect.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember the cover art?  How did it threaten the planet?  Did it replicate, expand, leave a path of devastation?  Did it eat people, absorb them, assimilate them, just kill them...?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

The idea of finding some alien life form frozen (or in some kind of statis) that runs amok on awakening is as old as science fiction. I suspect we will need a few more details to identify the specific story you are thinking of. If there are any details you can remember e.g. character names, or specific events, then please edit your answer to include them as they may be the vital clue.

It's got me thinking of "Vang the military form"

One the capsule was discovered, space crew sends one member to investigate. While in capsule, the alien form detects the presence of human and wakes up from deep sleep mode. Then , alien form invades space ship. I do not remember in details, but the alien form multiplies by converting human's host into their own and manages to escape the ship to land on nearby planet (not Earth) where it continue its expansion.

To @DannyMcG Yes, it is "The Vang: The Military Form". Much appreciate your response.This is awesome. :=)

@user11997143 I've posted "The Vang" as an answer now, please accept

@DannyMcG Thank you again. I do accept the answer. Much appreciate a feedback and suggestion from all who participated in this thread.

This is "The Vang:The Military Form" by Christopher Rowley.

Took you long enough; if you'd left it 'til the morning I would have given up and posted it myself.
